# Domain Name Server not changing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I recently moved my domain from ionos to another provider AWS, It moved successfully and showing in AWS registered domain and removed from the list of ionos domain list. I have changed the Name Server on AWS but still showing old records on who.is site. What is the way forward, for now, I want to use Name Server of AWS and point to elastic IP of ec2 instance.

Comment: So you updated your Name Server Records to match the name server records Amazon gave you? If you run a DIG command what do you see for NS records on your domain? There should be 4 records, each using a different top level domain (com, net etc)

Comment: ` dig eotrace.fr

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> eotrace.fr
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 52583
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;eotrace.fr.                    IN      A

;; Query time: 2588 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 18 09:39:12 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39`

Comment: That domain has no name server configuration, if you check with your registrar that the name servers have been added

Comment: Since I have moved the domain to aws and then added NS record as below. `ns-136.awsdns-17.com.
ns-1901.awsdns-45.co.uk.
ns-908.awsdns-49.net.
ns-1410.awsdns-48.org.`

Comment: Running a DIG returns nothing: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/

Comment: Response returned by Route 53
DNS response code NOERROR
Protocol UDP

`ns-136.awsdns-17.com.
ns-1410.awsdns-48.org.
ns-1901.awsdns-45.co.uk.
ns-908.awsdns-49.net.`